# Unechoed string input in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in C++ where I am supposed to receive a string from user without displaying it on screen (for example: apassword). I tried using `cin` and `gets` to accept the string. But both will echo the characters entered by user in console.

So is there any function or any other way of doing it in C++?

Comment: and Hi at beginning of post is removed automatically!

Comment: Yes, and that’s a good thing: we try to keep questions (and answers) to the point here. Not using “Hi” and “thanks” is *not* considered impolite on Stack Overflow. Anyway, have an upvote, good question.

Comment: check out *NCurses* (unix) and *PDCurses* (windows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to avoid that data being read via `cin` shows up on the console depends very much on the console; it's certainly operating system dependant.

On Windows, you can use the [`SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to enable/disable the echo for any file handle, including the standard input handle.

Something like

```
void enableStdinEcho( bool b ) {
    HANDLE hStdin = ::GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ); 
    DWORD mode = 0;
    ::GetConsoleMode( hStdin, &mode );
    if ( b ) {
        mode |= ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    } else {
        mode &= ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    }
    ::SetConsoleMode( hStdin, mode );
}
```

could probably be used to toggle the echo on stdin.

Comment: On windows system it worked like charm!now trying getpass with gcc-linux.

Comment: void enableStdinEcho( bool b ) {

 int ttyDevice = STDOUT_FILENO;
    struct termios termAttributes;
    /* Make sure file descriptor is for a TTY device.         */
     if ( ! isatty(ttyDevice) ){
        exit(1);
  }else {
          if (tcgetattr(ttyDevice, &termAttributes) != 0){
    exit(1);
    }else {
    if(b == false)
     termAttributes.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    else
     termAttributes.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    
    tcsetattr(ttyDevice, TCSANOW,&termAttributes);
    }
  }
    
} equivalent in unix/linux based.Got this stuff working.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not define a mechanism to do this.  You have to rely on a platform specific library.  For example with gcc/glibc use `getpass`

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#getpass

There might be other libraries that abstract these functions and provide a platform independent wrapper.

Comment: No need for a full fledged library, `tcsetattr` usually suffices on unices. The manpage for glibc `getpass` even says: "This function is obsolete.  Do not use it."

Comment: Yes tcsetattr would sufficiently do for gcc.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C++, iostream etc. question at all - it's specific to the terminal you're using.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558009/ansi-c-no-echo-keyboard-input) for ideas, and then ask a question specific to your terminal if it isn't covered there and you can't use ncurses.