# How do i prevent "cin" from changing lines in the output screen after each input

Tags: c++

how should i write or change the input code in c++ so that in the ouput screen there is no change of line. That is, even after encountering a "cin" statement and taking the respective input from the user and also after pressing enter the cursor remains in the same line . is there any way to do so? please help.

Comment: what about `cin >> a >>b`?

Comment: Which OS are you using? I believe there is no portable way to do this.

Comment: yes cin>> a >> b would work voluntarily.you can enter both the values in the same line with / without spaces but on pressing enter once there is a new line jump.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't prevent `cin` from doing this (mostly because `cin` itself isn't doing it in the first place). The only real cure for the problem is to use some alternative to `cin`, such as `curses`.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unechoed string input in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292231/unechoed-string-input-in-c)

Comment: @jerry coffin  i am not aware of the syntax of `curses`. is it the same as `cin`

Comment: @soumyadubey: No--`curses` is really a C library, so it uses normal C function calls with no operator overloading.

Comment: @soumyadubey : I think jerry has hit the bullseye. Else there is no way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: The only two realistic options are: (1) live with it, (2) start GUI programming.

Comment: thanks @Jerry Coffin. `curses.h` actually helped.

Answer (score 1):

The language and its standard library have no notion of screen or cursor.

What you want to do definitely depends on your architecture and operating system.  On POSIX systems, disabling echo on the terminal may be a starting point.