# Change colors of keywords in linux terminal while typing

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I'm writing an interpreter in C, which runs in ubuntu console. I want to change the colors of keywords like `int`, `double`, `function` while typing.

Example: `functio` should be white, but as soon as I finish typing a keyword `function` its color should be changed to blue.

Simple example that would answer my question: I want to set the text color in terminal to blue when the number of letters is odd and red when it's even and it should happen while typing (not after pressing enter).

How to operate on text in terminal and change its colors while typing?

Comment: See `ncurses` library

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal/558422

Comment: How do you process text input at the moment? If it's line oriented (as suggested by your "after pressing Enter"), then ditch that and start again with character based input. With that, it's a standard "how do I do syntax highlighting" question.

Comment: This is much harder than it seems, I advise against it. You will need to provide your own line editing functionality first. And if you are asking how to colour text in a terminal, you most probably don't know how to do line editing either. Look at *GNU Readline* or *editline* or similar libraries to understand the sheer complexity of line editing. You will have re-implement this functionality and add colour on top, because existing libraries don't allow for easy integration of colour.

Comment: @user2564301 I'm reading text from terminal  using scanf function. Because of that I can process the text only after user has finished writing and submited the code to the interpreter.

Comment: After some more pondering, I think one can integrate colour in GNU Readline. You would have to supply your own redisplay function (see `rl_redisplay_function`) which would call `rl_show_char` *and* set terminal colours as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live text editing on a terminal console is much of a black art, because there is no reliable way to be sure that the console supports any and all escape sequences that you need. For a full-screen editor, you could use `ncurses`, but "inline" is harder than it looks. An example: my otherwise fairly compliant Mac OS X's own Terminal handles single line input gracefully but it gets confused when a text string contains nonprintables or spans more than can fit in the Terminal's width.

The following not-so-quick (but still dirty) C program allows *very basic input*. A few of the hoops it required jumping through: on OS X, `getchar` echoes its input back to the command line; the terminal itself (!) does not forward its input to the running program until an Enter was entered. Other consoles may have other quirks.

With single-line editing working, the only remarkable thing is how to process the running line to display parts in color. That's left to walking over the string while it's being displayed, using ANSI Escape Codes to toggle color on and off. My syntax highlighting method is very basic; if you have many more keywords, you may want to look in a quicker way of looking them up. It's also  not able to handle wildcards, so you cannot highlight stuff like "any decimal number".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define PP_INVERSE  "\x1b[7m"

#define PP_RED      "\x1b[31m"
#define PP_BLUE     "\x1b[34m"

#define PP_RESET    "\x1b[39m\x1b[0m"

const char *keyword_list[] = {
    "int",
    "double",
    "function"
};


/* ha ha */
#define SURELY_LARGE_ENOUGH 256

char line_buf[SURELY_LARGE_ENOUGH] = "";

void display_line (char *text, int cursor)
{
    char *startptr, *endptr;
    int i;

    printf ("\r>");

    startptr = text;

    do
    {
        /* hop from one 'word' to another */

        /* check for non-word first */
        while (*startptr && !isalnum(*startptr))
        {
            putchar (*startptr);
            startptr++;
        }

        if (*startptr)
        {
            endptr = startptr;

            /* gather next word */
            while (*endptr && isalnum(*endptr))
                endptr++;

            /* check if it's a known keyword */
            for (i=0; i<sizeof(keyword_list)/sizeof(keyword_list[0]); i++)
            {
                if (keyword_list[i][0] == *startptr && strlen(keyword_list[i]) == endptr - startptr)
                {
                    if (!strncmp (startptr, keyword_list[i], strlen(keyword_list[i])))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (i<sizeof(keyword_list)/sizeof(keyword_list[0]))
            {
                printf (PP_INVERSE "%s" PP_RESET, keyword_list[i]);
                startptr = endptr;
            } else
            {
                if ((endptr - startptr) & 1)
                {
                    printf (PP_BLUE);
                } else
                {
                    printf (PP_RED);
                }
                while (startptr < endptr)
                {
                    putchar (*startptr);
                    startptr++;
                }
                printf (PP_RESET);
            }
        }
    } while (*startptr);

    /* erase any following leftovers */
    printf ("\x1B[K");

    /* position cursor */
    printf ("\r\x1B[%dC", cursor+1);
    fflush (stdout);
}

/* turn off echo for getchar
    see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558009/ansi-c-no-echo-keyboard-input
*/
void getch_disable_echo (void)
{
    struct termios t;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t);
    t.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
}

void getch_enable_echo (void)
{
    struct termios t;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t);
    t.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    t.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
}

int get_input (void)
{
    int cursor_pos = 0;
    int key;

    do
    {
        display_line (line_buf, cursor_pos);
        key = getchar();
        if (isprint(key))
        {
            if (!line_buf[cursor_pos])
                line_buf[cursor_pos+1] = 0;
            line_buf[cursor_pos] = key;
            cursor_pos++;
        }
        /* poor man's backspace */
        if (key == 127)
        {
            if (cursor_pos)
            {
                cursor_pos--;
                line_buf[cursor_pos] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (key == '\n')
        {
            printf ("\r%s \n", line_buf);
            line_buf[0] = 0;
            cursor_pos = 0;
        }
    } while (key != EOF);

    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    getch_disable_echo();

    strcpy (line_buf, "this is a function test");
    get_input ();

    getch_enable_echo();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see this already is quite a large program, and it only allows basic editing. I left out tab completion, cursor movement, undo, and various other niceties users may expect from a full line editor. Rather than re-inventing the wheel, you could look at the sources of GNU `readline` and check if it would be easier to adjust its redraw routine to allow your custom syntax highlighting.

Other than that, it works just nicely:

[image: screen recording of live input]